# Current location of the object inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

I created UIScrollView and added large image inside of the scrollview to scroll. My question is how should I know the current location of the image that I added inside of the scrollview like its X and Y? Like for example, I scroll the image horizontally then and I want to know what its new X and Y value of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See scrollview.contentOffset.  That should have the coordinates of the point that is visible in the top-left corner of the scrollview after any scrolling.

Comment: it seems the contentOffset's x and y always zero, not updating everytime I scroll the image inside of the UIScrollView.

Comment: Show us some code.  I just checked and my scrollView will change the contentOffset when scrolling happens.

Comment: yup, my problem, i used %d instead of %f in the NSLog. yay :)

Answer (score 3):

This is going to take a little bit of math. There are two properties (both `CGPoint`s) that are of importance to you:

- The `frame.origin` of your image, which is its *position within its superview*
- The `contentOffset` of the scroll view, which is the *visible portion of the scroll view*

Basically what you want to do is grab the `frame.origin.x` and `frame.origin.y` properties of the image  view, which will tell you where the image is relative to the absolute origin of the scroll view. Then, get the `contentOffset.x` and `contentOffset.y` of the scroll view and subtract them from the `x` and `y` of the image view. That should provide you the relative origin of the image view to your screen.

Comment: actually not working, frame.origin and contentOffset's x and y always return 0 value.

Comment: Then something is wrong in your code.  I've used this many times before to do similar calculations.

Comment: yeah, i just used wrong variable format in my NSLog, working now. thanks.